# How to access native apps on table view and able to use multiple selections

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.5

I am trying to create an app on xcode and I need to use a table view where i can select multiple applications to do a function and i was wondering how to do this, If possible I would like to do this on storyboard but I will do this through programing if it is not possible otherwise